# How to access my localhost website from my phone?

Tags: asp.net, localhost, ip

**Good day to all,**

I am trying to create my website locally, and perhaps access the website through my phone from the localhost. Forgive me I am just a beginner.

So I used ipconfig -all to find my IPV4 address and it was e.g
192.168.1.102

And on the ASP.net webapplication I ran, the address was:
https://localhost:44337

Hence, I was trying to access this Web Application of mine created on my PC, to be accessed on my phone. On my phone, I entered the address:
192.168.1.102:44337

I went into my firewall setting to add a new rule for inbound connection to allow all ports to be connected as well. But it still don't work. Both my PC and phone is connected to the same wifi.

Does anyone know the fix? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to configure an IIS server. This tool comes default in Windows (professional?), and there's lots of good resources on how to do this, all of which do a better job of explaining the process than I could do.
Essentially, you will need to:

1. Publish your site (Done through visual studio or cli)
2. Enable and configure your IIS
3. Create a new website in the IIS manager and point it towards the output of your web app publish

Answer (score 0):

After opening the neccessary firewall ports, check to see in which IP address your web application is running. I am assuming you are using some sort of HTTP webserver software like IIS(windows) or Apache(Linux). In IIS to do that you must go to your site bindings and where it says "**IP Address**", select **"All Unassigned"** (NOT localhost or 127.0.0.1)so that the web application runs in all network adapters and IP addresses.

See full IIS documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-the-iis-manager-in-iis-7-and-iis-8

Answer (score -1):

Follow the guide: https://medium.com/@manujsdeveloper/debug-a-website-local-or-remote-hosted-on-an-android-mobile-device-ff2c43527be1

You will need to set your phone in developer mode and get the OEM USB driver specific for your phone. and get a ADB running on your computer

I suggest supplement your knowledge with with links below, as some things are left out in the above guide and vice versa: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: what does this has to do with android, chrome and remote debugging?